# "Cannot open" when downloading APK on Huawei

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

I created a simple Android app in Kotlin to test wide angle camera with Camera2 and CameraX. The only device with wide-angle camera access we have is Huawei P30 PRO, Android 10 (API 29), with access to Google Play. When I installed first version of the app from apk (Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s)) the app launched, but I needed some improvements so I created the second app and second apk (I changed one or two lines of code). When we tried to launch it on this Huawei phone, we got a message "Cannot open". We tried different solutions, including:

- generate signed APK
- clear cache
- install app via APK Editor
- add tag `android:debuggable="true"` in Manifest

But none of those worked. APK Editor said that it needs file with .apks format, other solutions haven't worked too, we still are getting "Cannot open" message. I also tried to launch the app on Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus, Android 8, API 27 (this phone doesn't have wide-angle camera, so testing on it is pointless) and it worked with every APK I created. I did it just to check if this problem happens on every phone, but it seems like it is only with the Huawei phone we have. The app itself has no bugs. This is my `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:testOnly="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Camera2Sample"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What's interesting, the old apk which launched at the first time is still launching without any problem. Is there any other solution to launch this APK?

Comment: _The app itself has no bugs_ - you wish... :)

Comment: Hahahah I mean there are no serious issues in the main app code that could crash the app - so I will clarify that ;D

Comment: `"Cannot open" when downloading` AND `When we tried to launch it on this Huawei phone, we got a message "Cannot open".` do not match. When exactly? And can you insttall the app to begin with?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the old app first?